# Cannot connect to Postgres Database when running Quarkus Tests with Gitlab ci

Tags: database, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, quarkus

I am facing an issue when trying to config quarkus test running pipeline on GitLab.
I usually get the error
`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`
I used maven to execute tests

And here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: maven:latest

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: >-
    -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
    -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository
    -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true
    -Djava.awt.headless=true
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: >-
    --batch-mode
    --errors
    --fail-at-end
    --show-version
    --no-transfer-progress

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      alias: localhost
      command: [ "--tls=false" ]
  variables:
    # Instruct Testcontainers to use the daemon of DinD, use port 2375 for non-tls connections.
    DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
    POSTGRES_NETWORK_MODE: "host"
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

  script:
    - 'mvn test'
```

Also my application.properties file:

```
quarkus.http.root-path=/my-service/api

# Database Configuration
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.devservices.enabled=true
quarkus.datasource.devservices.db-name=my_db
quarkus.datasource.devservices.username=admin
quarkus.datasource.devservices.password=admin
quarkus.datasource.devservices.port=5432
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=16

# Configuration for Swagger
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.security-scheme=jwt
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.security-scheme-name=accessToken

# OIDC Configuration for Dev Profile
%dev.quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8088/realms/my-realm
%dev.quarkus.oidc.client-id=my-service
%dev.quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=aa12LO1abcjI6khjklSTUAZUF0xj123W
%dev.quarkus.oidc.tls.verification=none

# SWAGGER
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.operationIdStrategy=PACKAGE_CLASS_METHOD
```

I tried many ways:

- Create a java class test to dynamically the host implementing `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager`
- Add `quarkus.datasource.devservices.container-network=host` into my `application.properties`
- Add `alias: localhost` into `dind` services in `.gitlab-ci.yml`
- Hardcoded the host of the `jdbc` url inside `application.properties` to `docker`
- Declare variable for db host and tried to use it in `application.properties` as below:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variable:
  TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE: "host.docker.internal"
```

`application.properties`:

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://${TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE}:5432/my_db
```

Please help me. Thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: Do you see the image getting pulled? The container getting started? What is the error message? Do you have a link to a (failed) pipeline run and/or the gitlab project?

Comment: Hi. The images are all pulled but when quarkus tried to start to run the tests. It failed with the error "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections" and that's all. I cannot provide the link since the project is private. Sorry

Comment: What about my other questions? Does the container get started? And can you provide a link to the repository (and failing pipeline runs)?

Comment: Hi. Sorry. I double checked and saw that the images and containers started normally with the log: "(build-7) Container is started (JDBC URL: jdbc:postgresql://docker:5432/db?loggerLevel=OFF)". The repo is private I have no rights to expose the link to you... so sorry

Comment: My guess is that we should set `QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_JDBC_URL=postgresql://docker:5432/my_db` or even unset it alltogether (since the testcontainers integration of quarkus should inject the configuration into the test)

Comment: As mentioned above, I tried this way, too. But it did not work either and it still had the same error. But in the end, thank you so much for your effort